# i have a sql generated report with data like 24-1,but while generating in excel it displaying like 24-jan,...what is the solution in sql?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a `sql` generated report with data like 24-1,24-2,but while generating in `excel` it displaying like 24-jan,24-feb. What is the solution in `sql`?

```
SELECT distinct 
ITEM_NO,
```

Assume item is 24-1
then report displaying

```
IGM NO  ITEM NO
237      24-Jan
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `single quotation mark` as the first character in a cell. It tells `Excel` to treat the rest of the string as text.

```
SELECT DISTINCT '''' + ITEM_NO,..
```

Comment: i have tried it ,but a single quotation mark as the first character irritating..any better idea?

Comment: `single quotation mark` is a special character for Excel. It can be removed by selecting the cells.